# Freeing tuple created by std::make_tuple()

Tags: c++, stl

I'm assuming that tuple object created by std::make_tuple() is dynamically allocated on stack. My question is how to free/delete this object, when its life cycle reaches the end state.

```
std::tuple<int,int> myTuple = std::make_tuple(3, 7);
delete myTuple; // is this correct?
```

Comment: `delete` must used only in pair with `new`. You do not call `new std::tuple<int,int>(3, 7)` therefore you must not call `delete`. Moreover it is impossible - try to compile your code.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm assuming that tuple object created by std::make_tuple() is dynamically allocated on stack.

There is no such thing as *dynamically allocated in the stack*.

What happens is that you get an object (instance of tuple class) in the stack, which can have pointers to dynamically allocated memory (on the heap).

> How to free/delete this object, when its life cycle reaches the end state?

Each class has, *or should have*, a destructor that deallocates all this dynamic memory when it goes out of scope (usually the end of the command block, think curly braces). There is no need for you to free it manually, the way you don't free an `std::string`.

Use the `delete` keyword only for things you have manually allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot explicitly call `delete` since you did not explicitly called `new`. You can limit the scope of `myTuple` which will trigger its destructor which will free the memory.

```
{
   std::tuple<int,int> myTuple = std::make_tuple(3, 7);
   ...
}
// myTuple goes out of scope.
```